# How to run python script on multiple cores in windows from command line?

Tags: python, windows, cpu-cores

I have a python script and need to run this script for different dataset. How can I run the script using multiple cores on  windows? In my case, I would like to use all 4 cores.

Comment: Simply run it multiple times and Windows will distribute the processes over all available cores.

Comment: @kazemakase , I think needs one instance of script running in multiple cores. Use multiprocessing, eventually Windows will decide how many cores to use based on cpu demand

Comment: @be_good_do_good That's not how I read the question. *run this script for different dataset* sounds like a typical [embarassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problem, no multiprocessing required at all.

Comment: @kazemakase, may be you are right. In that case, what ever you suggested should work

Comment: @be_good_do_good, your comment seems to suggest that multiprocessing allows a single instance of a script to run on multiple cores. It does not. It's a framework to coordinate the operation of multiple Python processes.

Comment: Sure, use **GNU Parallel**.